# Pitt Bull with knee and hip problems

Tags: dogs, injury

I have a 6 year old female Pitt Bull who got out when she was about a year old. She came back limping in her back legs and hip area. When I took her in the vet said she could have been hit by a car but she also had her knees genetically on the side of her legs instead of where they belong, which would cause her more and more problems later on. 
What is the best thing I can do for a dog now 5 years later, who has trouble walking because of her hip and knee issues?

Answer (score 1):

All of the things mentioned above are definitely important and can help you dog be more comfortable. You could also try out knee/hip braces for dogs that are flexible enough to be worn daily. I've personally used a knee brace after my dog tore her ACL and couldn't have been happier with it.

Another thing you could check out is getting some sort of harness to help bear some of your dog's weight when you're going for walks. They have rear support harnesses out there that are meant to do just this.. Depends on how much difficulty your dog has getting around and how much help she needs.

Comment: Remove spammy link, new editor has links to one vendor for several similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't cure it without risky surgery that I would not recommend, but you can do some things for any pets that have movement-related disabilities. These also work for pets with arthritis.

1. **Cooling/heating pads.** These are a great solution for any animal in need of a little pain relief. They provide great comfort to your pet while keeping them cool in the summer and warm in the winter.
2. **Lots of love.** While not really doing anything to cure the problem at all, this can definitely help comforting your pet.
3. **A massage.** It sounds crazy but this can actually help a lot. It relaxes your pet and its muscles.
4. **Lots of bedding.** Providing lots of places to lie down and take a break can help significantly. Your dog won't have to travel so far to get to a nice bed to take a nap in.

Hopefully I helped you, if none of these work, consult a vet and they may be able to give your dog a medicated pain reliever.